# Can you use the LIKE operator in SOQL queries via the REST API?

Tags: soql, rest-api

As the title states, can you use `LIKE` in SQOL queries via the REST API?

Even with this basic query:

```
select Id from Account  where BillingState like 'VIC%'
```

I'm getting an error back:

> REST Response fault: [{"message":"SOQL statements cannot be empty or
>   null","errorCode":"MALFORMED_QUERY"}]

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: If you're still having problems post your code

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes you can. SOQL in the rest API supports all the same constructs that its SOAP older brother does. Remember to pass the SOQL as the 'q' parameter in the URL,and to URLEncode the soql when putting it in the query, e.g.

`https://na1.salesforce.com/services/data/v25.0/query?q=select+id+from+account`

Comment: Yup, just realised the problem was that I wasn't encoding the `%` sign. I'd actually tested encoding using what turns out to be a broken encoder online, it told me that `%` is just `%`, not `%25`!

Comment: Try using workbench.developerforce.com next time to formulate the SOQL query / REST request

Answer (score 17):

I think the issue is with the url encoding of the % in the like clause.

I just tried the following in the Workbench Rest API and it worked.

```
/services/data/v25.0/query?q=select+id+from+account+where+BillingState+like+'VIC%25'
```

Comment: Giving the accept to to @superfell because he got in there first, I just couldn't accept it within 10 minutes of asking it seems!

Comment: Yes. Totally fair. I got distracted by my day job and when I turned back @superfell had the answer sorted.

Comment: @DanielBallinger hmm, day job - remind me what's that?